# Search the existing keywords in the picture to find out the position of keywords in the picture ?by python

Tags: python-3.x, ocr

Search the existing keywords in the picture to find out the position of keywords in the picture by python

Comment: Can you provide more details? What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: From a nameplate picture, read the position of a keyword in the picture, and then identify the text information attached to this position.
I want to know if I can make this function with python.